# python script to clone all the code repos from github code organisation

Tags: python, github, automation, clone, git-clone

There are many ways to clone the GitHub code repos from an organization. Now considering there are some repos which are private and public, I was looking into a solution where an automated script or code logic would solve my purpose of cloning the code repos irrespective of repo type. I tried various measures but couldn't land to simple automated solution. I tried using curl command, but it was slow as the density of code repos to be cloned was above 200+ code repos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try below python code snippet to clone all repos:

Here we use git ssh to clone each repos in a secure way to accommodate both public/private code.

Sometimes due to network issues , it may show remote hung/packet-loss messages which leads to repo partial/no cloning.  to avoid that please set below parameter in the shell.

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400
```

Assuming that your git global credentials are updated.

Code :

```
import os
# Define your repo list
list = ["repo1","repo2"]

#Loop it through repo's list
for repo in list:
    #Clone the each repo using ssh git clone command in most secure way
    cmd = "git clone git@<git ssh url>/{}".format(repo)
    print("Starting to clone {}".format(repo))
    os.system(cmd)
    print("Finshed cloning {}".format(repo))
    print("#####################################")
    print("")
```

Answer (score 0):

putted together info from two resources to clone all organizations private repositories:

```
# https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/using-github-api-in-python
# https://github.com/libgit2/pygit2/issues/554

# pip3 install PyGithub pygit2

from github import Github
import pygit2

# using an access token
g = Github('TOKEN')
org = g.get_organization('ORG NAME')

callbacks = pygit2.RemoteCallbacks(pygit2.UserPass('TOKEN', 'x-oauth-basic'))
# Clone repo
for repo in org.get_repos():
    pygit2.clone_repository(
        url=repo.clone_url,
        path=f'/home/<Username>/PycharmProjects/Backup/{repo.name}',
        callbacks=callbacks)
```

Comment: This script does not work. Getting ```File "script.py", line 16, in <module>``` ```_pygit2.GitError: too many redirects or authentication replays```